Set text at the circle end point in doughnut chart
Using HTML5 Canvas i am trying to add extra text in the ChartJs V3.8 doughnut chart. Chart is rendering correct.
Red circle value always be dynamic but not static.
I am trying to add text at the end of red circle where ever it will end as it's value not static.
I am not getting how to calculate the correct position of red circle end point.
here i want to show the text with dynamic red circle value and dynamic position



Script - Tried with this way


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Chart.js Doughnut with Custom Text</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.8.0"></script>
    <style>
         #myChart {
            padding: 20px;
            background: #f0f0f0;  /* Light gray background to visualize padding */
            border: 1px solid #000; /* Border to visualize the actual canvas edges */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="chart-container">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<script>
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels: ['PVR', 'Other'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Dataset 1', // For the red semi-circle
            data: [95.2, 4.8], // Percentage for the red segment
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)', // Red color
                'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)' // Transparent for the invisible part
            ],
            borderColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)',
            borderWidth: 1
        },
        {
            label: 'Dataset 2', // For the green semi-circle
            data: [77.6, 22.4], // Percentage for the green segment
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)', // Green color
                'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)' // Transparent for the invisible part
            ],
            borderColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)',
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        layout:{
            padding : 50
        },
        rotation: 225, // Start from the top
        circumference: 270, // Make it a half-circle
        cutout: '90%', // Adjust the thickness of the donut here
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    },
    plugins: [{
        id: 'customText',
        afterRender: (chart) => {

            
            const ctx = chart.ctx;
            const dataset = chart.data.datasets[0];
            const meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(0);
            const total = dataset.data.reduce((acc, value) => acc + value, 0);
            const redEndAngle = Math.PI + (dataset.data[0] / total) * Math.PI; // End angle of the red segment

            const centerX = chart.chartArea.left + (chart.chartArea.right - chart.chartArea.left) / 2;
            const centerY = chart.chartArea.top + (chart.chartArea.bottom - chart.chartArea.top) / 2;
            const radius = meta.data[0].outerRadius;

            // Coordinates of the endpoint of the red segment
            const endX = centerX + radius * Math.cos(redEndAngle);
            const endY = centerY + radius * Math.sin(redEndAngle);

            // Optionally, add text to mark the point (for demonstration)
            ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
            ctx.font = '12px Arial';
            ctx.fillText('End of Red', endX, endY);  // Position text appropriately

        }
    }]
});
</script>


</script>
</body>
</html>



i also tried to set it using custom html div

afterRender: (chart) => {
                const chartArea = chart.chartArea;
                const textElement = document.getElementById('custom-text');
                const dataset = chart.data.datasets[0];
                const meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(0);
                const total = dataset.data.reduce((acc, value) => acc + value, 0);
                const redEndAngle = chart.options.rotation + (dataset.data[0] / total) * chart.options.circumference;

                const centerX = (chartArea.left + chartArea.right) / 2;
                const centerY = (chartArea.top + chartArea.bottom) / 2;
                const radius = meta.data[0].outerRadius;

                // Calculate the position for the custom text
                const textX = centerX + radius * Math.cos(redEndAngle);
                const textY = centerY + radius * Math.sin(redEndAngle);

                // Adjust for the document position
                const canvasRect = chart.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

                // Set the position of the custom text element
                textElement.style.left = `${canvasRect.left + textX - textElement.offsetWidth / 2}px`;
                textElement.style.top = `${canvasRect.top + textY - textElement.offsetHeight / 2}px`;
                textElement.style.transform = `translate(-50%, -50%)`; // Center the text
                textElement.style.position = 'absolute';
            }



All the variables are there in the meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(0) object: centerX, centerY, endAngle, outerRadius. The rest is simple trigonometry which you have provided.


const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ['PVR', 'Other'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Dataset 1', // For the red semi-circle
      data: [95.2, 4.8], // Percentage for the red segment
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)', // Red color
        'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)' // Transparent for the invisible part
      ],
      borderColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)',
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    layout: {
      padding: 50
    },
    rotation: 225, // Start from the top
    circumference: 270, // Make it a half-circle
    cutout: '90%', // Adjust the thickness of the donut here
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      tooltip: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [{
    id: 'customText',
    afterRender: (chart) => {

      const ctx = chart.ctx;
      const dataset = chart.data.datasets[0];
      const meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(0);
      const centerX = meta.data[0].x
      const centerY = meta.data[0].y
      const endAngle = meta.data[0].endAngle
      const radius = meta.data[0].outerRadius;

      var destX = centerX + Math.cos(endAngle) * radius
      var destY = centerY + Math.sin(endAngle) * radius

      ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
      ctx.font = '12px Arial';
      ctx.fillText('End of Red', destX, destY); // Position text appropriately

    }
  }]
});
#myChart {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  /* Light gray background to visualize padding */
  border: 1px solid #000;
  /* Border to visualize the actual canvas edges */
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.8.0"></script>

<div class="chart-container">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>



